# C program division error?

Tags: c

When i run the following code i get correct answers for addition,subtraction,multiplication but division gives me wrong answer:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, add, sub, mul, div;
    printf("Enter numbers \n");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &num1, &num2);

    add = num1 + num2;
    sub = num1 - num2;
    mul = num1 * num2;
    div = (float)(num1 / num2);   // typecasting

    printf("Addition answer = %d \n", add);
    printf("Subtraction answer = %d \n", sub);
    printf("Multiplication answer = %d \n", mul);
    printf("Division answer = %.2f \n", div);

    _getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

[image]

what would be the reason of Division = 0.00??

Comment: Notice that `<conio.h>` is not a standard C header. It is specific to your implementation (and e.g. don't exist on Posix or Linux systems)

Comment: Take the habit to **enable all warnings in your compiler** and learn how to **use the debugger**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div = (float)(num1 / num2);   // typecasting
```

is wrong, you should cast the operands

```
div = (float)num1 / (float)num2;
```

Of course, you should have declared

```
float div;
```

and with all warnings a good compiler (like [GCC](http://gcc.Gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -g`) would have noticed the discrepancy for `printf`

Actually, you'll better use `double` instead of `float`  since [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) with `%.2f` expects a *double* argument... (but a `float` value is promoted to a `double` one when passing arguments to `printf` ....)

So your code should actually be

```
double div = (double)num1 / (double)num2;
printf("Division answer = %.2f \n", div);
```

Read about [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and [the floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and [what every programmer should know about floating point](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf)

Comment: .. Depends what is what to be achieved

Comment: Anyway a +1 as I think that is maybe the intended behaviour

Comment: *"%.2f expects a double argument"* sounds a bit misleading (to me). - You don't have to use `double` with "%.2f" because `float`s are promoted to `double` in the variadic argument list of the `printf()` call.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `div` as an integer, but print it as a floating-point number. The binary formats of integers and floating point numbers are not the same, so it causes the wrong value to be printed.

Either declare `div` as a `float`, or print it as the integer it is.

You should build with more warnings, as this would have been the cause of two warnings: First the assignment of a `float` to an `int`, then the printing of an `int` as a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

```
float num1, num2, add, sub, mul, div;
```

needs to be a float or it will floor down to 0.00

Or you need to cast them with a float

Answer (score 0):

It is doing integer division. I.e whole numbers - then convert to floating point

Answer (score 0):

`dev` is defined as an integer, and then printed with a `%f` format. You need to define it as a float.

Comment: No, as a `double`; see [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) - but the `float` -> `double` conversion would have happenned at argument passing...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
int num1, num2, add, sub, mul;
float div;
printf("Enter numbers \n");
scanf_s("%d %d", &num1, &num2);

add = num1 + num2;
sub = num1 - num2;
mul = num1 * num2;
div = (float)(num1 / num2);   // typecasting

printf("Addition answer = %d \n", add);
printf("Subtraction answer = %d \n", sub);
printf("Multiplication answer = %d \n", mul);
printf("Division answer = %.2f \n", div);

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you declared div as integer. so If you will store division of two float number in integer variable then you will get wrong answer.

You should declare div as float. Like,

```
float div;
```

and your type conversion should like,

```
div = (float)num1/(float) num2;
```

Then you will get correct answer.